# adb hell command (not a typo)

Tags: android, adb

I have a question about ADB, does anyone know what is the difference between:
`adb shell` & `adb hell` commands?

I'm wondering if except the "hellish" terminal color(only on Linux, in Windows you just get some prefixes) there are any other differences?
Seriously check yourself.

[image]

Comment: I just discovered this myself accidentally. I ROFLed.

Comment: what the hell! just stumbled upon this!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Reading the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/f987398723b06538821162dadde7d7d2c9e0fb29/adb/commandline.c):

```
if(!strcmp(argv[0], "shell") || !strcmp(argv[0], "hell")) {
    int r;
    int fd;

    char h = (argv[0][0] == 'h');

    if (h) {
        printf("\x1b[41;33m");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    if(argc < 2) {
        D("starting interactive shell\n");
        r = interactive_shell();
        if (h) {
            printf("\x1b[0m");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
```

...

```
            if (h) {
                printf("\x1b[0m");
                fflush(stdout);
            }
```

This code confirms that if the `shell` or `hell` command starts with an `h`, extra control sequences for changing terminal colors are output but nothing else.

Comment: Therefore is just an easter egg :)

Comment: Looks like it was removed :-( https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/180036/

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no other difference between the two.

Comment: It's funny because of the irony of it ;)